In the movie "La vache et le prisonnier", what is the name of the actor who plays a marquis who sews ribbons on the back of his pants?
In the 1959 movie "La vache et le prisonnier" ("The Cow and I"), the main character Charles Bailly, a French POW in WWII, is played by Fernandel. At some point, rather early in the movie, he stops by a party of French POWs who are supposed to saw tree trunks, but show very little enthusiasm in their work. These prisoners are arranged in pairs, each affected to one trunk.
One character, called Colinet, is played by Albert Remy. His trunk-partner is not credited. His part, though short, is interesting. He claims to be an aristocrat, a marquis, and at every victory of the Allies, he sews ribbons on the back of his pants. He looks like the French actor Claude Rich, but he is not him.
Here is a snapshot of him:

Can anyone find out who this actor is? Thanks!

Could it be Rene Havard, as "vicomte Bussière", prisonnier de guerre (POW)?

@OldPadawan Thank you for your efforts, but no, René Havard does not look at all like the sewer-rather-than-sawer. I am surprised to see him crdited as "vicomte Bussière" in this page in English. In the french Wiki page he is just credited as "Bussière". https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Vache_et_le_Prisonnier And indeed, he is quite recognizable as one of the french POWs who work in the same farm as Fernandel at the very beginning of the movie and encourage him to flee, even though they know they will be punished for it (which happens a bit later).

On this picture you can see René Havard sitting on the left with Maurice Nasil (Bertoux, short, with glasses), and Bernard Musson (Pommier, tall), both standing on the right, very early inthe movie.
https://picclick.fr/Fernandel-La-vache-et-le-prisonnier-Verneuil-Original-393237944264.html#&gid=1&pid=1
